# How to save block attributes when the output doesn't change

Tags: plugin-development, block-editor

I have a block with some settings that affect the editor only. So not the output. The issue is that when I change these settings, the output doesn't change. Then Wordpress does not detect the change, and does not trigger the "update" button. Next time I open the post the changes to my block-level settings are gone, because they were not saved.

*Can I manually trigger the update button from my block?*

**code**

```
import Edit from "./components/edit/edit"
import PreviewInEditor from "./components/edit/editor-preview";
import BlockSettings from "./components/block-settings/BlockSettings";
import { useBlockProps } from '@wordpress/block-editor';

export default function Editor( props ) {

    function update_settings( settings ) {
        props.setAttributes( { ...props.attributes, settings } );
    }

    if( props.isSelected || props.attributes.price_records.length === 0 ) {
        return ( <div { ...useBlockProps() }>
            <Edit {...props} /> 
            <BlockSettings settings={props.attributes.settings} onChange={update_settings} />
        </div> );
    } else {
        return ( <div { ...useBlockProps() }>
            <PreviewInEditor {...props} />
            <BlockSettings settings={props.attributes.settings} onChange={update_settings} />
        </div>);
    }

}
```

Comment: It looks like you've hidden the important parts of your code, and it's unclear how the `Editor` component is used in your question. If your block has attributes that have changed then that on its own is enough, even if you don't use those attributes in your save component. Remember, there are server rendered blocks that have `null` as their save component. I would also strongly advise against storing objects in an attribute, this is an anti-pattern, and bad practice, and likely the root cause of your problem

Comment: @Tom J Nowell Where would you recommend storing editor settings for a block then? Separate attributes? ( that's gonna be unorganised imo )

Comment: there's not enough information or context to say, you've shared nothing about what these settings are or what they do, or how they're implemented, the only clues are that they're stored in an object, involve some form of async, and exist in a blackbox component called `BlockSettings`, you need to provide more information, right now everything is so abstract it's difficult to even talk about it. It may even be the case that block attributes don't make sense for this but there's so little context to go on I can't advise. The only thing I can say is flatten out your hierarchy

Answer (score 0):

Actually an assumption I made in the question was wrong; The update button doesn't only change when the output of the save function changes. It also changes when the attributes are **changed**.

However I found a small bug, which you can't really see it in the provided code. In my `BlockSettings` component I was using `useState` to update the settings inside to the component. I would also emit the `settings` immidiately after assigning them.

`useState` is however an async function. So in fact I was emitting the old value. Since I emitted the old value the attributes were **identical** to the values before. Therefore not triggering an update.

The fix was quite easy. Using `useEffect` to react on the changed value did the trick for me.

*So if the update button isn't triggering, doublecheck if you actually changed the attributes.*

Comment: The output of the save function depends on the attributes and can _only_ depend on the attributes. Given the attributes X Y and Z the save function **must** always return the same output, if it does not then block validation will fail. You cannot and must not use local state in the edit component to influence the save component, and to expect local component state to persist beyond the lifetime or scope of the edit component is unreasonable, and would be considered a bug if it happened

Comment: Also, your question implies you meant post update, as in the editor sees that the post being edited can be updated, but your answer actually suggests that what you meant was a component re-render. The terminology here is super important as what you said and what you meant are very different things. Also you should not be maintaining both local component state and attributes for the same things, that too is an anti-pattern

Comment: @TomJNowell I did mean post updates. The underlying issue was that I returned identical values, due to asynchronous behavior in React. That was the reason a post update didn't trigger.

Comment: can you update your question to include the missing code? People with the same issue but for other reasons are going to find this and be extremely confused, especially when the answer you've posted to refers to code that cannot be seen, and mentions actions that are never explained and just labelled as asynchronous. Given how many upvotes your question has it'll likely gain more visibility and attention from other people, increasing the confusion